# How to detect a swipe and make the player GO rotate towards the end of the touch Android Unity

Tags: unity, android

I am making a game where the user can swipe on the screen and the player gameobject will turn towards the end of the swipe.

I am using the following to detect the end of the swipe:

```
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            swipeEndPos = touch.position;
            swipeDistance = (swipeEndPos - swipeStartPos).magnitude;
            if (swipeDistance > minSwipeDistance)
            {
                Vector3 swipeEndPoint = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint (swipeEndPos);

                player.Turn (swipeEndPos);
            }
        }
```

And the following to make the player turn towards the end position:

```
     public void Turn(Vector3 direction)
     {
       transform.Rotate (new Vector3(0,direction.y,0), Space.Self);
     }
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your setup 2D or 3D?

Comment: It is 3D, sorry I didn't mention it

Comment: Do you have a terrain or a plane to act as a raycast receiver?

Comment: no, should I add one? I am using the player (initially at (0,0,0)) as point of reference.

Comment: Well if your setup is 3D you should cast a ray from the screen point at the end of the swipe, and you something to receive raycast. You can do it without raycasting too, but it would require some complex projection calculations, which is overkill for this purpose.

Comment: i am using screen.ScreenToWorldPoint (swipeEndPos); and then I log the results to get an idea of what's going on, but the result vector3 seems very high value.

Comment: Because that is not the correct way. You are probably using a perspective camera, which expands as it goes further away, which means the axis of screen point is not the same point it will match in the corresponding plane on viewport. Also if your camera is tilted, the projected pixels gets looser as it goes further away from where camera is.

Comment: yes you are right, i am using a perspective camera and it is tilted (3rd person) do you suggest i switch to an orthographic view?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, it was as S.Tarik said, the perspective view was giving the "wrong" coordinates. Switched to orthographic, now things run smoothly. Thanks Tarik :)

Comment: S. Tarik you should post it as an answer so I can upvote you

Comment: It is fine, just accept yours. :)